# Where is "notify" button in the iOS TestFlight for external texts

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, beta-testing

Where is the "notify" button in the iOS TestFlight for external tests

In the new Itunes Connect TestFlight the "notify testers" button has gone. 
Some users was not notified since last year.
How can I notify users for new builds, or something else.

[image]

What I already have tried:
Add a new build does not notify users.
Change "what to test" does not notify users.